# How to validate post code input data?

Tags: c#, validation

That's what I've done so far

```
     Console.Write("Enter your post code >");
        post_code = Console.ReadLine();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(post_code))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter correct data");
            return;
        }

        else if (post_code.Length != 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter correct data");
            return;
        }
```

I need : -The first digit must not be 1, 8 or 9.
         - The first digit must match the state according to the following table:

State        : NT| NSW| VIC| QLD| SA| WA| TAS|

First Digit  : 0  | 2 |  3 |  4 |  5 | 6 | 7 |

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at regex : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx that's what you need :)

Comment: You might want to give the english link instead of the french one :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx also to understand how to use I recommend taking a look at the reference and examples at http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: I have to do it with if , else if , try parse statements. anything elese

Answer (score 1):

[Regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) can be used to validate post code:

```
    Regex postCodeValidation = new Regex(@"^[0234567]\d{4}$");
    if (postCodeValidation.Match(post_code).Success)
    {
        // Post code is valid
    }
    else
    {
        // Post code is invlid
    }
```

**Please note**: in code above post code is considered to be 5 digits (to change length - you will need to replace `4` in *Regular expression pattern* `[0234567]\d{4}` with appropriate number).

Comment: It won't compile (either `"[0234567]\\d{4}"` or `@"[0234567]\d{4}"`), it also validates invalid input such as `abc23456` due to lack of string delimiters.

Comment: @GeorgeTsoukatos Then verify length of the code and use for loop through all characters of your post code and validate [IsDigit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh.aspx) method (additionally verifying first character).

Comment: I only have to do it with :   if, if … else, if … else if … else constructs
Nested ifs
CASE and switch constructs

Comment: @GeorgeTsoukatos Looks like you want to validate each character of postal code separately - then best option will be to use `switch` operator where cases of all digits are joined (share same block of code) and called within function for each character.

Comment: @GeorgeTsoukatos Please refer to 3-rd revision of answer from Konrad Morawski - he provided solution with usage of `if` only (you can open it by click on **edited [some time ago]** link in the bottom of his answer).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if state is part of your four character postcode contains state too. But if it does not, you can do it like this:

```
Dictionary<string,string> statePostCodeMap = new Dictionary<string,string>();

// Populate the dictionary with state codes as key and post code first character as value

if(!post_code.StartsWith(statePostCodeMap([NameOfVariableThatHoldsState])){
// Incorrect post code
}
```

Edit: Based on user comments:

This is what you can use then:

```
if !((string.Compare(state, "NT", true) == 0 && post_code.StartsWith("0"))){
// Incorrect Data
}
else if(<similar condition for other values>)
...
```

I assume this is some sort of learning exercise.

Comment: I only have to do it with : if, if … else, if … else if … else constructs
Nested ifs
CASE and switch constructs

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace PostCodeValidator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var regex = new Regex(@"^[0234567]{1}\d{3}$");
            var input = String.Empty;

            while (input != "exit")
            {
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch(input));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Non-regex solution:

```
    static bool ValidPostCode(string code)
    {
        if (code == null || code.Length != 4)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var characters = code.ToCharArray();
        if (characters.Any(character => !Char.IsNumber(character)))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if ("189".Contains(characters.First()))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Another, without LINQ:

```
    static bool SimpleValidPostCode(string code)
    {
        if (code == null || code.Length != 4)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if ("189".Contains(code[0]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (!"123456789".Contains(code[i]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

`I only can do it with : if, if … else, if … else if … else constructs Nested ifs CASE and switch constructs`

If `for` loop isn't on your list of allowed language constructs either, you could still try:

```
    static bool SimpleValidPostCode(string code)
    {
        if (code == null || code.Length != 4)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (code[0] == '1') return false;
        if (code[0] == '8') return false;
        if (code[0] == '9') return false;

        return "0123456789".Contains(code[1]) && "0123456789".Contains(code[2]) && "0123456789".Contains(code[3]);            
    }
```

Comment: I only can do it with : if, if … else, if … else if … else constructs
Nested ifs
CASE and switch constructs